# C# .NET Take Action as parameter for method that provides a function that can be executed from lambda instantiating this Action

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

to make it simpler what I just wrote basically means I want something like this:

```
var someClass = new someClass((func1, func2) =>
{
  if (cool)
  {
    func1(cool);
  }
  else
  {
    func2(cool);
  }
}
```

Is this possible? I tried with an Action but that didn't work. I would really appreciate some help :D

Comment: Tried `Action<Action<bool>,Action<bool>>`? This isn't really idiomatic C# ... An interface with differing implementations would probably be simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
  public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(Action<Action<bool>, Action<bool>> func)
    {
    func(
            (i) =>{
                Func1(i);
            },

            (j) =>
            {
                Func2(j);
            });


    }

    public void Func1(bool cool)
    {

    }

    public void Func2(bool cool)
    {

    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var someClass = new SomeClass((func1, func2) =>
          {
              var cool = true;
              if (cool)
              {
                  func1(cool);
              }
              else
              {
                  func2(cool);
              }
          });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tried before. But how do I extend this? Can I assign some functionality to the func1 and func2 actions, so they actually do something?

Comment: Ok i edit it. You can call the first Action in the constructor of the SomeClass class

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need :D

Answer (score 0):

```
 var f = new Func<int>(() => { return 1; });
 var result = f.Invoke();
```

Is that what you are after?

syntax with input and output is

var myfunction = new Func((x,y,z) => { return a;});

var a = x.Invoke(x,y,z);

From edit comment

```
 public class someclass
 {
      private Func A = ......
      private Func B = ......
      public void somemethod(type x)
      {
           if(x) this.A.Invoke();
           else this.B.Invoke();  
      }
 }
```

Comment: No, not really. I want to have a function or something in my class. And be able to execute them from this parameter.

Comment: You could just have Func members of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that takes Action parameters and returns one of them based on some criteria, so that the return Action can then be executed at the callsite.

```
Action method (Action a, Action b)
{
    if (cool)
    {
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        return b;
    }
}
```